# TypeError working with Sails and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I'm running through [this tutorial](https://www.built.io/blog/2014/09/how-to-get-started-with-sails-js/) for Sails, but it uses Mongo and I'd rather use MySQL. Unfortunately this is running me into an error when I try to POST and add a record to the database, but I can't figure out why.  It seems to work fine when I use the localDiskDb, but flunks out with MySQL.

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at createCB (/api/controllers/UserController.js:16:52)
```

UserController.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  create: function(req, res){
    var params = req.params.all()

    User.create({name: params.name}).exec(function createCB(err,created){
      return res.json({
        notice: 'Created user with name ' + created.name // The error is on this line
      });
    });
  }
};
```

routes.js:

```js
module.exports.routes = {

  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },
  'post /User': 'UserController.create'
};
```

User.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: just try printing `err`. You should handle error cases too.